# c# Xna keydown with a delay of 1 sec

Tags: c#

im writing a tetris in xna. i have a class with a method rotateBlocks. When i press the "Up" arrow key. i wanna have that when i hold the button down for 1 sec or more that it executes the arguments in the first else if(rotating the blocks fast) right now nothing is happening. i have declared oldState globally in the class. if i remove the gametime check in first the else if the block will rotate fast imedietley. if i try to step through the code with linebreaks the resolution get f****d up

public void RotateBlocks(loadBlock lb, KeyboardState newState, GameTime gameTime)
        {
            _elapsedSeconds2 += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

```
        if (lb._name.Equals("block1"))
        {

            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && !oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                // the player just pressed Up


                if (_rotated)
                {
                    lb._position[0].X -= 16;
                    lb._position[0].Y -= 16;
                    lb._position[2].X += 16;
                    lb._position[2].Y += 16;
                    lb._position[3].X += 32;
                    lb._position[3].Y += 32;
                    _rotated = false;
                }

                else if (!_rotated)
                {
                    lb._position[0].X += 16;
                    lb._position[0].Y += 16;
                    lb._position[2].X -= 16;
                    lb._position[2].Y -= 16;
                    lb._position[3].X -= 32;
                    lb._position[3].Y -= 32;
                    _rotated = true;
                }


            }
            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                // the player is holding the key down
                if (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds >=1)
                {
                    if (_rotated)
                    {
                        lb._position[0].X -= 16;
                        lb._position[0].Y -= 16;
                        lb._position[2].X += 16;
                        lb._position[2].Y += 16;
                        lb._position[3].X += 32;
                        lb._position[3].Y += 32;
                        _rotated = false;
                    }

                    else if (!_rotated)
                    {
                        lb._position[0].X += 16;
                        lb._position[0].Y += 16;
                        lb._position[2].X -= 16;
                        lb._position[2].Y -= 16;
                        lb._position[3].X -= 32;
                        lb._position[3].Y -= 32;
                        _rotated = true;

                    }
                    _elapsedSeconds2 = 0;
                }

            }
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but in a Silverlight application. This has to be OS oriented, because I have found this issue in winforms too

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your gameTime check is only checking how long has elapsed since the previous tick.

You need to store the time when they first press the key, and then compare the difference between that and the current time.

Answer (score 0):

ElapsedGameTime is the time since the last time Game.Update() was called.  So if you game loop is running at a constant 60 times a second, ElapsedGameTime would always be 1/60 second.  You need to record TotalGameTime when the key is initially pressed, and use that in comparisons in future updates.

Comment: do you have any good example to provide ?? im really new to xna

Comment: You would do it in pretty much the same way as you store the old state.

Comment: i have so the blocks move 1 block down every one sec with. And that is working. Can't understand why it won't work
public void BlocksTickingMove(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            _elapsedSeconds += (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;


            if (_elapsedSeconds >= 1)
            {
                MoveBlock();
                _elapsedSeconds -= 1;
            }
        }

Comment: You are using "if (_elapsedSeconds >= 1)" in one place, and "if (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds >=1)" in another, and can't understand why they're working differently?

Comment: hehe. i must be blind. well now it rotates every one sec slowly when i press and hold the button

Comment: Because you reset _elapsedSeconds to 0 every time it fires.

Comment: it works now, thx alot. can i upvote you when i have only asked one question ??

Answer (score 0):

@Michael is correct, you need to do something like

```
// where integertype is int or long etc
integertype startPress = 0;

public void RotateBlocks(loadBlock lb, KeyboardState newState, GameTime gameTime) {

    _elapsedSeconds2 += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

  if (lb._name.Equals("block1"))
        {
            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && !oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                // the player just pressed Up
startPress = GameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

                if (_rotated)
                {
                    lb._position[0].X -= 16;
                    lb._position[0].Y -= 16;
                    lb._position[2].X += 16;
                    lb._position[2].Y += 16;
                    lb._position[3].X += 32;
                    lb._position[3].Y += 32;
                    _rotated = false;
                }

                else if (!_rotated)
                {
                    lb._position[0].X += 16;
                    lb._position[0].Y += 16;
                    lb._position[2].X -= 16;
                    lb._position[2].Y -= 16;
                    lb._position[3].X -= 32;
                    lb._position[3].Y -= 32;
                    _rotated = true;
                }


            }
            if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                // the player is holding the key down
                if (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds - startPress >=1)
                {
                    if (_rotated)
                    {
                        lb._position[0].X -= 16;
                        lb._position[0].Y -= 16;
                        lb._position[2].X += 16;
                        lb._position[2].Y += 16;
                        lb._position[3].X += 32;
                        lb._position[3].Y += 32;
                        _rotated = false;
                    }

                    else if (!_rotated)
                    {
                        lb._position[0].X += 16;
                        lb._position[0].Y += 16;
                        lb._position[2].X -= 16;
                        lb._position[2].Y -= 16;
                        lb._position[3].X -= 32;
                        lb._position[3].Y -= 32;
                        _rotated = true;

                    }
                    _elapsedSeconds2 = 0;
                }

            }
```